# Removing the common elements in i+1 th vector of a list in base R

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop

I was wondering how if I could find & remove the common elements in `i+1`-th vector of a list (in base `R`)?

For example:

```
x = list(a = 1:5, b = 3:7, c = 6:9)      # Initial list
common <- # your solution                # ? find common values

 for(i in 1:length(x)) {

  # your solution: ?create `b` removing common elements with `a`
  # your solution: ?create `c` removing common elements with `b`
}
```

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/outersect-the-opposite-of-rs-intersect-function/

Comment: Do you need `x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x[-length(x)], x[-1])`

Comment: @rnorouzian. I think it is the other way around i.e. `x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x[-1], x[-length(x)])`. if you want `6 7` for 'b' and '8 9'  for 'c'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are comparing the adjacent elements, use `setdiff` on the `list` with `last` and `first` element removed and update the 'x' `list`

```
x[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x[-1], x[-length(x)])
```

Comment: @rnorouzian. Not clear about your doubt.  May be create an object `x1 <- x[c('a', 'b', 'c')]` and then do `x1[-1] <- Map(setdiff, x1[-1], x1[-length(x1)])`

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: @rnorouzian. I found your another post.  Isn't that `x[order(sapply(x, min))]`

Comment: Oh great, actually I'm trying to see if I can always keep the output from the following regardless of how `x` list is provided:  `x = list(0:5, 0:40) ; 
y = lapply(list(dbinom(x[[1]], 5, .9), dpois(x[[2]], 50)), round, digits = 6) ;
c(list(x[[1]]), lapply(2:length(x), function(i) x[[i]][y[[i]] != 0]) )`

Comment: In other words, I want to keep the output above regardless of whether we provide `x = list(0:5, 0:40)` or `x = list(0:40, 0:5)`

Comment: @rnorouzian. I think you need `Map(function(u, v) u[v != 0], x, y)` based on your previous comment with 'x' and 'y' lists

Comment: @rnorouzian. Also, if you want to keep the first element as such, then do `c(x[1], Map(function(u, v) u[v != 0], x[-1], y[-1]))`